# Can't mount disk (VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem)

Tags: linux, centos, mount, hard-drive

Tried to mount a disk (hardware raid) but failed.

```
#mount -t ext4 /dev/sda /data

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

#dmesg | tail -1
       EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

what am I doing wrong?
I saw that many posters with similar problem were request to post the content of fstab so here it is:

```
#cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Aug  6 11:29:15 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=276c97cc-9c5f-496f-a56f-ac3a45c58a26           /           ext4    defaults,usrquota,grpquota  1 1
UUID=3978f122-03d4-48db-adeb-6fc8a2c624c4 /boot                   ext2    defaults        1 2
UUID=1251c6d8-c417-48df-9cf4-2f56e3a823a6 /tmp                    ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=95fd67df-7172-4ac9-9264-0b50819a203a swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

CentOs 6

Updates:

```
# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       32  244198584 sdc
   8       33     102400 sdc1
   8       34    4194304 sdc2
   8       35    2097152 sdc3
   8       36          1 sdc4
   8       37  237802496 sdc5
   8       48  244198584 sdd
   8       49     102400 sdd1
   8       50    4194304 sdd2
   8       51    2097152 sdd3
   8       52          1 sdd4
   8       53  237802496 sdd5
   8        0 21484255232 sda
   8       16 21484255232 sdb
   9        1    4192192 md1
   9        3  237671232 md3
   9        2    2096064 md2
   9        0     102336 md0

#fdisk -l | grep sda
Disk /dev/sda: 21999.9 GB, 21999877357568 bytes
```

Comment: What does `cat /proc/partitions` say?

Comment: I've added the output to the question

Comment: Try commands `pvscan`, `vgscan`, `lvscan` ... perhaps your ext4 resides in LVM volume?

Comment: all of these command don't exist on my machine, should I install them? it's a hardware raid 5

Comment: Is that two separate RAID-5 arrays? Is there any data on the RAID-5? It would be interesting to see the output of `hexdump -C </dev/sda | head -40` and likewise with `sdb`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using mount you have to mount the partition not the drive itself eg `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /data`

Comment: # mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /data

mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist

Comment: /dev/sda1 was just an example.  I would suggest running an `fdisk -l` to see what drives/partitions are available and then try mounting the one you want from there.

Comment: in fdisk -l I can see /dav/sda (I've updated my post with the data from fdisk)

Comment: I doesn't look like you have created any partitions on that raid.  Create a primary partition with fdisk eg `fdisk /dev/sda/`.  When the menu comes up `n` for a new partition select the defaults if you only want one partition. Select `t` to change the type of partition you want I believe 83 is Linux then `w` to write the changes. Then run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` to format the newly created partition.  Or if you are not to savvy with command line a GUI utility like gparted will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! it did the trick but it appears that fdisk doesn't allow more than 2TB partition and I needed 22TB parition. After some googling I could find this [excellent post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29078/how-to-partition-22tb-disk) which solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: If you could please mark this as answered so people don't keep posing answers in an old thread.

Comment: I created a ext4 partition using `parted` and was mounting with the correct command, but it was giving the same error. Using `mkfs.ext4` as suggested by @joeg1ff worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can get that error in the dmesg when you are creating a new Logical Volume but you forget to run the mkfs command which actually builds the file system. What I am trying to say here is that in order to be able to mount a partition you should make sure first that you ran mkfs after you created the Logical Volume or else it will complain same as in your example.

1. Create a Logical Volume from the Volume group vg:
    **lvcreate -L 2G --name lv_data vg**
2. Make the file system an ext4 type:
   **mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg-lv_data**
3. Mount it:
   **mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vg-lv_data /data**

Jumping/missing step 2 it will complain with the error: *VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem*.

Answer (score 3):

It clearly says wrong file system type, give below command and check which file system it is.

```
file -sL /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
```

**output:**

> /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv: SGI **XFS** filesystem data

Cross check the fs type in /etc/fstab, if it is other than `xfs`, change it to `xfs` and in /etc/fstab and then try mounting